Cannot see Tables in Azure Using MS Access
I am using the Linked Table Manager in Access and connecting to our Azure DB (which works, I see the information_schema abd sys schemas) but none of the tables I have in the DB (AdventureWorksLT) are in the window to link to, is there a security setting in Azure I need to setup to make the tables in the DB available in the Access front end?  I have tried a DSN, they weren't available there either.

You must assign permissions to the account used in your connection to the database from Access. The db_datareader should do the trick.
You could use T-SQL:
USE MyDatabaseNameHere;
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER UserNameHere;
GO

Run this in SSMS or use the Query Editor in the Azure Portal. You'll need to use an account with db_owner or db_securityadmin role (like sa account) to add the role.

OK ty, very helpful - so I am using the user I created when I created the server/DB in Azure.  I ran the script successfully, but still do not see the tables.  When I created a table called "tblEmployees" and used this line, it does link - just doesn't work using Linked Table Manager "DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC", strCnn, acTable, "tblEmployee", "tblEmployee""

Have you refreshed the table list in the navigation panel? Or try closing and reopening the database?

Yes I have done both, I even did a compact and repair... same results.
